# You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator

Tags: powershell

This works

```
Dependencies\iis7psprov_x86.msi /qn /l* $SnapinInstallLog
```

But this doesn't

```
$SnapinInstaller = "Dependencies\iis7psprov_x86.msi"
$SnapinInstaller /qn /l* $SnapinInstallLog
```

I get the following error :
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator.
+    $SnapinInstaller /q <<<< n /l* $SnapinInstallLog

How do i get the snap-in to install with the variable $SnapinInstaller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PowerShell recognizes `$SnapinInstaller` as a variable and evaluates it - to a string.  If you want PowerShell to "call" the command named by the variable then you use the call operator `&` like so:

```
& $SnapinInstaller /qn /l* $SnapinInstallLog
```

While you can use `Invoke-Expression`, it is usually avoided, especially with user provided data, due to the possibilty of script injection attacks e.g.:

```
PS> $SnapinInstallLog = Read-Host "Enter log file name"
Enter log file name: c:\temp\snapin.log; remove-item C:\xyzzy -r -force -whatif
PS> Invoke-Expression "$SnapinInstaller /qn /l* $SnapinInstallLog"
```

Badness happens here because the user was able to inject arbitrary script.

OTOH if you have a bunch arguments represented in a single string (and no user provided input), `Invoke-Expression` can come in handy in that scenario e.g.:

```
$psargs = "\\$computer -d -i 0 notepad.exe"
Invoke-Expression "psexec.exe $psargs"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because powershell treats $SnapinInstaller like a string, not a command.

The first way to do what you want I can remeber is to write

Invoke-Expression -Command ($SnapinInstaller + " /qn /l* " + $SnapinInstallLog)

This works with *.exe, I didn't try it with *.msi.